# initialize singleton instance by using static technique, to prevent using synchronized? how it actually works?

Tags: synchronization, singleton, instance

Initialize singleton instance by using static technique, 
to prevent using synchronized? how it actually works?

I have seen some where like *without using synchronize block* we can create a thread-safe singleton instance?

How does actually it works? How the both are same?

Comment: Please add more details. What language are you referring to? Providing an actual code sample could help others to better understanding the issue.

Comment: Sorry about it and I have been using java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to an implementation such as:

```
class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The line: `private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();`
is evaluated at class loading time (which means that if an attacker loads this class multiple times - multiple instances will be created!).

A class is (usually) loaded only once, before the first time it's used (either by calling static field/method or by creating an instance). This mechanism is synchronized by the JVM:

> The implementation of the Java Virtual Machine is responsible for
>   taking care of synchronization and recursive initialization by using
>   the following procedure...

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Comment: Thank you and it has helped